# Calculating average on YTD from YTD prev month value SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder

This seems a bit ugly bcs I know this some kind of math problems and I am no good in solving math problems specially when I'm going to implement this to SSRS code. So I need some guidance.

I want to calculate an Average for my YTD data. Illustration in table :

| Month | This Month | YTD (Prev Month) | YTD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan 2022 | 1 | - | - |
| Feb 2022 | 2 | 1 (From this month Jan 2022) | 1.5 (Average from this month and YTD PrevMonth) |
| Mar 2022 | 2 | 1.5 (From Feb 2022 YTD) | 1.75 (Average from this month and YTD PrevMonth) |

From here, I still can't find a suitable solution for this problems. How can I get the YTD from previous month calculation for the current YTD Prev Month value report. Because my Tablix didn't show like the illustration table I create above. My report looks like this :

| Indicator | This Month | YTD (Prev Month) | YTD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 | 1.5 |
| B | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| C | 2 | 1.5 | 1.75 |

I use a parameter to filter the data based on the selected month. How do I calculate the **average** from previous month then I can use that value for **YTD (Prev Month)** for today month data report ?

Let me know if my explanation not clear enough.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is based on calculations in your images.

You can use custom code to store the ytd of previous month

Add the following code to your report (average will start calculating from the first non zero month)

```
Public Dim previous_ytd As Decimal = 0

Public Function PrevYTD( v1 As Decimal  ) As Decimal

If previous_ytd =0
previous_ytd = v1
Else
previous_ytd = (v1+previous_ytd)/2
End If

Return previous_ytd

End Function
```

For your YTD (previous month) expression use

```
= Code.previous_ytd
```

For your YTD expression use (change the field name to match your own)

```
= Code.PrevYTD(Fields!value.Value)
```

[image]

[image]